# Probability problems of taking balls

Tags: probability

In every round, I can randomly take 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 number of balls uniformly. 
What is the probability that total number of balls taken will >= 16 in the following round?

1st round : How many balls I take won't larger than 16, probability total number of balls >=16                          is 0

2nd round : In this round the only chance that total number of balls >= 16 is I take 8 balls in the 1st round and second round. So the probability total number of balls >= 16 will be 1/9 * 1/9 = 1/81.

What is the probability in the 3rd round, 4th round? Is there a general model for it?

Comment: your question is not clear sir

Comment: I already edit the question, can you please take a look again?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is still not clear. What do you mean by '0~8 balls'? How many balls are there to choose from? How many types of distinct balls are there? What do you mean by a 'general model'?

Comment: It means that I can take 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 balls in random for every round.

Comment: "I can randomly take " You must specify the probability law: are we to asusme that we take 0 to 8 _uniformly_? "total number of balls already taken... in the following round" Again, not clear what "already" means, and what is the "following" round. "3rd round is 1/81" is, again, a bad writen sentence, it means nothing. You -seriously- need to state the problems in a clear way, before attempting to solve them. We cannot understand it, and it make us wonder if you understand it.

Comment: I edit again, can you understand the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(n,k)$ is the probability of a sum of $n$ after $k$ draws then you have $$p(n,k)= \frac19 \sum_{j=0}^8 p(n-j,k-1)$$ starting with $p(0,0)=1$ and $p(n,0)=0$ for $n \not = 0$.

This is easy enough to program, and you are looking either for $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 16} p(n,k)$ as the probability of having a sum of $16$ or above, or for $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 16} p(n,k)-p(n,k-1)$ as the probability of the sum moving from below $16$ to $16$ or above. This gives the following (rounded) probabilities after $k$ rounds:

```
k   Cum_sum     Diff_sum
0   0           0
1   0           0
2   0.012346    0.012346
3   0.226337    0.213992
4   0.537266    0.310928
5   0.776558    0.239293
6   0.908325    0.131766
7   0.966855    0.058530
8   0.989168    0.022313
9   0.996741    0.007574
10  0.999085    0.002344
11  0.999758    0.000673
12  0.999939    0.000181
13  0.999985    0.000046
14  0.999997    0.000011
15  0.999999    0.000003
16  1.000000    0.000001
```

Comment: Wow! thx~ i also got the cum_sum answer using combination equation, the answer is correct !